# Multi monitor setup: Mouse suddenly not locked to some games anymore

Tags: pc, mouse, watch-dogs, dead-island

I've been using Windows 8.1 for a few weeks now, but since yesterday the mouse cursor stopped being locked to some games (Watch_Dogs, Dead Island). Watch_Dogs worked just fine two days ago, didn't try Dead Island before. Other games like Loadout work just fine.

I didn't install any new drivers (even tried reinstalling my graphics drivers though).

I have a Nvidia GTX 770, but as I already said. I installed the new driver a few days ago when it came out and Watch_Dogs worked just fine with them.

Comment: Are you playing Fullscreen Windowed instead of Fullscreen? Some games let the cursor "escape" while in menus and stuff (Borderlands 2 does, but not in FPS mode). I've also had some poorly thought out Unity games that just don't bother to lock the mouse at all, but it doesn't sound like that's the problem.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15751/when-extending-my-desktop-across-multiple-monitors-how-can-i-limit-my-mouse-t?rq=1 Not quite a dupe but there might be answers here.

Comment: @Studoku I already saw that one, but those are just workarounds. I want to fix the heart of the problem.
In the end I just aimlessly reinstalled stuff and rebooted until I gave up and then a few hours later it started working again. I have no idea what caused it or fixed it, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when playing TES:V. After some research I found this program called Primary Lock. I know the website looks really fishy, but it is completely free of malware and viruses.

All it does is lock your mouse to the main monitor for as long as the program is open.

[Primary Lock](http://www.theisozone.com/downloads/misc/freeware/primary-lock/)

Comment: I hate it when my sites have mallards.

Comment: I think you meant to say malware, not a kind of duck.

Comment: @Dispensador the damn ducks are taking over the world..

Comment: Long life to all birds!